# How to save all element index after removing element in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

```
sentence = [[1,0,3],[2,0,0],[0,0,5]]
empty = []
for element in sentence :
    for icelement in element :
        if not icelement == 0:
            empty.append(icelement)
        
         
        
print(empty)
print(empty[2]) #this should give 3 or empty[8] should give 5
```

I did many attempt but stil having problem. I know this is because python automatically updating the elements index but dont know how to control it. Any suggestion will help me.

```
num = [1,0,4,5]
print(num[3]) #gives 5
for n in num :
    if n == 0:
        num.remove(n)

print(num[3])# doesnt exist.
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Why would `empty[2]` be `3` or why would `empty` even have 9 elements for you to be able to do `empty[8]`? Please provide expected output and how it is formed.

Comment: Hey, @Bünyamin Mete, Python index begins at **0**. So if you want to print **number 3** you need to use index 1, like this: `print(empty[1])`

Comment: can you please add more information, what output you are expecting, are you trying to collect all the elements which are not zero ? what index you are want to store.

your current output should look like as [1,3,2,5], are you expecting the same ?

Comment: Are you just trying to flatten the array?

Comment: btw it is a bit weird to use `if not x == 0:`, for "not equals" you would usually use `if x != 0:`

Comment: @Matiiss surely just `if x`?

Comment: @JeffUK I guess in this case yes, but in general case for not equals usually `!=` is used (with numbers at least) and that simply caught my eye

Comment: I am sorry because of complexity. I mean when ı remove or pop the element from the list. Python updating the whole index.

Comment: yes, the index updates, but you don't remove any elements from the list

Comment: I am sorry because of the complexity. I edited post. Can u check it ?

Comment: "this should give 3 or empty[8] should give 5" What do you think the entire `empty` should be? Why? I can't understand why you expect these results, and I also have no idea what the two pieces of code are supposed to do with each other. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to preserve the position in the original flattened list while removing some elements?

The options are either flatten the list, leave the zeroes in place; just ignore them.

```
empty = [item for sublist in sentence for item in sublist] #[1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
print(empty[2]) # returns 3
```

Or do something with a dictionary, use the original position in the flattened list as the key.

```
count = 0
empty = {}
for element in sentence :
    for icelement in element :
        if not icelement == 0:
            empty[count] = icelement
        count +=1

print(empty[2]) # returns 3
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code and the description of the output, it looks like you want to flatten you nested list and remove the zeros. At the same time you want to retain the original flattened indices.

This is not possible with a list as the indices necessarily go from `0` to `len(the_list)`.

You can either keep the zeros:

```
sentence = [[1,0,3],[2,0,0],[0,0,5]]

empty = [i for l in sentence for i in l]
# [1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
```

Or use a different container. Dictionaries enable to have arbitrary keys:

```
from itertools import chain

empty = {i:v for i,v in
         enumerate(chain.from_iterable(sentence))
         if v}
# {0: 1, 2: 3, 3: 2, 8: 5}

empty[2] 
# 3

empty[8]
# 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexes of python starts with 0

It gives you back the list:

```
[1, 3, 2, 5]
```

so to get the second element we should do:

```
print(empty[1])
```

so the code looks like this now

```
sentence = [[1,0,3],[2,0,0],[0,0,5]]
empty = []
for element in sentence :
    for icelement in element :
        if not icelement == 0:
            empty.append(icelement)
        
         
        
print(empty)
print(empty[1])
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 5]
3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write the same loop in one line and it gives the same result as your code.

```
sentence = [[1,0,3],[2,0,0],[0,0,5]]

empty= [icelement for element in sentence for icelement in element if icelement != 0]
print(empty)
```

**output:**

```
[1,3,2,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

one liner solution:

```
sentence = [[1,0,3],[2,0,0],[0,0,5]]
counter = [j for i in sentence for j in i if j!=0]
```

we take `j` in case `j` is not equal to `0`